# Pick up a preferred value from an array

Tags: powershell

I have an array as listed below stored in

```
$q
```

```
first name: Niranjan 
Last name: Raguraman
Type: Employer
Location: India 

first name: Sunil
Last name: Kumar 
Type: Employee
Location: US
```

Now I will implement a foreach here and iterate through the values. I want the powershell to return the variable based on my preference.

```
foreach ($a in $q.type)
{
"Not sure how to make it return the variable in the order of my preference 
1st preference - Employee
2nd preference - Employer if there is no employee, then return employer as the value 
"
}
```

Hope I made the question clear

Comment: Nope question isn't clear. Please show the desired result given the data you have.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. does `$q | sort type` give the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$employee = @($q | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq 'Employee'})
if($employee.Count -gt 0) { 
    #1st preference - Employee
    $employee
} else {
    #2nd preference - Employer if there is no employee, then return employer as the value 
    $q
}
```